Corner of front door sticking out, letting heat and humidity inside
I just moved into a rent house that was built in 2020. There are a few signs of the builders rushing to finish, but one I don’t know how to solve is that the right corner of the door seems to be bent inwards leaving a gap between the door and the weather strips. This allows heat and humidity to get in from outside, and I can see light from outside over a fairly large region inside the door frame.
Also, we have to push or pull the door for the deadbolt to latch properly. It seems that at the top right, the door about a half inch too far out. Living in Florida, rain and mold are also a concern with the gap, Is there a simple fix for this?



Is the door wood or a composite? Is it warped?

We just moved in but it appears to be wood, and doesn’t look warped.

I know it appears to be wood. Is it? Pull the knob and verify. Either the door slab is warped or the jamb is twisted. You'll need to determine which before we can help with confidence. Use a straightedge or a string and see what you see.

If this is a rent house, you really should get with the landlord before doing any real work.

either the door is warped or the frame isn't square/plumb.  I assume you could warp a door if the hinges were put on under stress.

You rent? Then only solution is contact the landlord.

I’m voting to close this question because a renter needs to contact the landlord.

Looking around the door I don’t see any bare wood so it may be composite. But my landlord lives in San Francisco so I’m not sure if she’d be able or willing to hire someone to fix it.

Using some weatherstripping or adjusting the stripping you have now is the easiest to seal it up.  It looks like the door needs replacing if warped or the door frame/wall is out of plumb, which is probably needs landlord permission to fix.

That’s a great point, I can probably find different weatherstrips that can at least improve the gap issue until (and if) my landlord is able to provide a more permanent fix.

@SolarMike, that's not a valid reason to close. The question may be purely academic and still provides topical value to the community. It's not for you to decide what's socially appropriate or legal.

I have had issues like that happen before with existing conditions. Maybe not as bad as yours but the fix I have in mind may work.
I use backer rod, the material that is used when caulking large gaps, it is stuffed into the gap and minimizes the amount of caulk needed among other benefits.
Backer rod comes in a number of different diameters, 1/2" 3/8" and 1/4". There are larger sizes too but I don't think you will need to go any bigger.
It is available at hardware stores in possibly the weatherstripping or caulk section.
Backer rod link
I made a little sketch that shows where it will go. What it does is fill in behind the weatherstripping you have so it hold it out farther away from the door stop, so it will met the door where the gap is now. You will need to try a few diffwerent sizes and it will not need to go all the way up and down. Only where it is needed.
I have had trouble before, when the backer rod is too big, keeping it in place. So if the smaller of the sizes will work, that will be better.


Take the door off the frame. Remove the middle and top hinges from the frame. Insert one layer of cut-to-size cardboard under the middle hinge and two layers under the top hinge. Reinstall the hinges and the door. This should fix it.
Otherwise, as others have said, either the door is warped, or the jambs are not plumb and square. One of the two issues will have to be corrected.

This would shift the door along its closed position plane. That's not the problem here. It needs to shift along its 90 degree open position plane.
